# How to select visibility of specific worksheet at the opening of Excel using Spreadsheet XML

Tags: worksheet, xml-spreadsheet

I am getting spreadsheet xml from a code logic (Flex Grids to spreadsheet xml).
I have 3 worksheets (A, B, C) in that spreadsheet xml.
I am opening this spreadsheet xml in Excel. 
I want to view worksheet B when I am opening the spreadhseet xml in Excel.

Is there any tag/code, I need to add so that worksheet B will be visible at initial?
I can add that code in code logic

Thanks ... Atul

Answer (score 0):

Add `<ActiveSheet>` tag in `Namespace` section of `XMLSpreadsheet`.

e.g. `<ActiveSheet>1</ActiveSheet>`, where `1` is the second worksheet of the spreadsheet excel.